# Login to another website and parse data

Tags: parsing, authentication, httpwebrequest

There is php page, let's call it `http://www.aaaa.org/login.php` which has two `textboxes` (name="username" and name="password") and a button.
And there is my `.aspx` page from which I want to login to that `.php` page. Once logged in I want to retrieve and parse some content of a subpage `http://www.aaaa.org/details.php?id=1234`.
I tried some code but it always retrieves the content of the `login.php` page so I assume I can't login at all.
Can you show me the exact code how to do this?
The language is C#.

Comment: Let's see the code that you have tried, which doesn't work exactly how you like.

Comment: You need to do a "post" just like the login.php does when the button is clicked. You need the names of the textboxes and button (do a view source) and if anyone changes them, your code will stop working. It's a brittle thing, but sometimes you have no choice.

Comment: one of my tries:
http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/850/code1a.png

Comment: updated:
http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/4536/code2z.png

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use an HTTPClient library.  Something like this:
http://www.codescales.com/

This will enable you to login and access the client application.  Note that your application will be fragile and subjected to the web app and it's changes.  So if they change the field names, your app will have to change as well.  But it will work for what you are trying to achieve.

I would also suggest writing this as a separate library and not directly in your ASPX code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient req = new WebClient();

        CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
        //myCache.Add(new Uri("http://www.aaaa.org/login.php"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("login", "passw"));
        myCache.Add(new Uri("http://www.aaaa.org/login.php"), "Digest", new NetworkCredential("login", "passw"));

        req.Credentials = myCache;

        string results;
        results = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(req.DownloadData("http://www.aaaa.org/login.php"));
    }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string TheUrl = "http://www.aaaa.org/details.php?id=2923";
        string response = GetHtmlPage(TheUrl);
        TextBox2.Text = response;
    }
```

---------------- updated: -----------------

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient req = new WebClient();

        CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
        myCache.Add(new Uri("http://www.aaaa.org/login.php"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("login", "passw"));

        NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection();
        postData.Add("username", "login");
        postData.Add("password", "passw");
        req.UploadValues("http://www.aaaa.org/login.php", postData);

        req.Credentials = myCache;

        string results;
        results = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(req.DownloadData("http://www.aaaa.org/login.php"));
```